# Regex to allow all characters with the length limit of 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a sentence,

```
  let message = "Hi thank you for #num#num bye"
```

Here in place of #num, there can be any values but atleast 1 and maximum 5 characters can be there. So here is how I'm replacing the #num like below.

```
  Hi thank you for .{1,5}.{1,5} bye
```

So Im forming the regex like below,

```
 let regex =  /^Hi\s*thank\s*you\s*for\s*.{1,5}.{1,5} bye$/i

 let usermsg = "Hi thankyou for 6 bye"
```

Ideally the above one should fail since I have substituted only one value. Minimium there should be 2 values.

but when I try to test using below,

```
  console.log(regex.test(usermsg) ? "Pass" : "Fail", "==>", usermsg );
```

It is failing. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: `Hi thank you for #num#bird bye` <-- would this be valid?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes its valid, the below is invalid "Hi thank you for #num#birdss bye" . Totally it can be upto 10. more than that it should be failure.

Comment: `for\s*.{1,5}.{1,5}` ==> `for 6`. The `\s*` matches nothing, the first `.{1,5}` matches the white space and the second `.{1,5}` matches the `6`. That's why it fails. try using `\S{1,5}\S{1,5}` instead

Comment: @HaoWui have tried,  Hi thank you for 1234 2123 bye => Still its failing. Please help

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The only issue is that with `\s*` after 'for' you allow **zero or more** space characters. So with your test message, the space in ' 6' is considered as 1 character part of the first `.{1,5}` group.

Changing `\s*` to `\s+` will solve your problem.
`+` matches **one or more** characters

Solution -

```
let regex =  /^Hi\s*thank\s*you\s*for\s+.{1,5}.{1,5} bye$/i
```

Here is a nice tool to test your regex and debug - https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for you reply, But what there can no space or can be multiple spaces for the other portions of the sentence except #num . Only within that #num portion spaces also should be counted.. For example, .{1,5}.{1,5} can be 1234 12343is valid. Please help

Comment: In that case, modify your regex to not allow space as the first character in your .{1,5} group

Comment: I have tried applying .(\\S{1,5}) ,  It works for everything except if we give 2 characters it is failing again. Kindly help